# HandDropChances and ArmorDropChances set to 0.0F doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i'm trying to summon a mob with items in hands and on body but i don't want it to loot this stuff when killed. I want to manage the loot via a death loot table.

Here is my command :

```
execute at @p run summon skeleton ~ ~ ~ 
{
    PersistenceRequired:1b,
    Health:200f,
    DeathLootTable:"my_data_pack:entities/loot_skeleton_boss",
    HandItems:[
        {
            id:"minecraft:iron_hoe",
            Count:1b
        },
        {
        }
    ],
    HandDropChances:[
        0.0F,
        0.0F
    ],
    ArmorItems:[
        {
            id:"minecraft:leather_boots",
            Count:1b,
            tag:{display:{color:0}}
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",
            Count:1b,
            tag:{display:{color:0}}
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",
            Count:1b,
            tag:{display:{color:0}}
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:jack_o_lantern",
            Count:1b
        }
    ],
    ArmorDropChances:[
        0.0F,
        0.0F,
        0.0F,
        0.0F
    ],
    Attributes:[
        {
            Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:200
        },
        {
            Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.35
        },
        {
            Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:25
        },
        {
            Name:generic.armor,Base:15
        }
    ]
}
```

The skeleton looks ok, it spawns with the right stuff etc, and i also get the loot from the given loot table but i sometimes get the stuff it is wearing. Is there another way to avoid the skeleton giving his stuff ?

Comment: Did you use Looting when killing the skeleton?

Comment: Yes, but i don't want it to loot his stuff even with looting. I just want the content of the loot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-2958) that has existed for a long time. It is fixed in the current snapshots, so if you are already playing 1.13.x or 1.14.x, I recommend you to update to the snapshots, they are generally better than the "stable" versions before them.

Comment: Oh ... Is there another option ? It is for an Halloween event on a server, and switching version would require a lot of work so we don't use snapshots. Otherwise I'll try to make it like that

Comment: Give noone a looting sword. I prefer fighting with an axe anyway.